# Rspec failing to test a hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, rspec

I'm trying to create a simple menu list and although the program is working, the test is failing. Does anyone know how I can solve the problem? I'm currently getting failings which says: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWwIF.png)

This is my rspec test:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xYK1.png)

And this is the code to pass the test:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/infhU.png)

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for code next time, just paste it in your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're simply missing a £ in your test.

Comment: Do you mean " expect(menu.list_menu).to include "Beef_Burgar £5.99"? if so, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe the number of spaces is the problem, your code puts like 3 of them between the name of item and its price. Your code will work once you make sure the strings are the same.

Comment: Ahh..great! Thanks for the help. I've solved the problem. :)  It was indeed the spaces that proved problematic. If you've got any advice on how to improve the code that I have, I'm welcome to hear about.

Comment: @YvoTan Please, mark the answer as correct if it solved your question. This helps creating rich content at Stackoverflow :)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @TarekN.Elsamni. I've marked it as correct.